# nodejs can't work with SSL

Tags: node.js, sockets, ssl

Im trying to run nodejs app to work with my php project. the problem is I think with SSL which is enabled in the server.

I have two files that I found in my root directory after SSL install: domain.com.csr and domain.com.key and I tried to combine them to connection while creating https server, but nothing worked for me.

so far I have this code:

```
var socket = require('socket.io');
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');

var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app);

var io = socket.listen(server);

app.get('/test', function(req, res) {
    res.send('hello world');
    console.log('visited test')
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function (client) {
    console.log("New client !");

    client.on('message', function (data) {
        console.log('Message received ' + data.name + ":" + data.message);

        io.sockets.emit('message', {name: data.name, message: data.message});
    });
});

server.listen(8080, function () {
    console.log('listen me on: 8080');
});
```

and it works well when I'm trying to visit http://ip:8080/test so it means that node server is working, but when I try to create socket connection on my view file `var socket = io.connect('http://ip:8080');` it gives me error:

```
The page at 'https://www.domain.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://ip:8080/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1446818946199-0'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

so the problem is clear enough, but how to deal with it?
also I have tried this connection:

```
var socket = io.connect('https://www.domain.com:8080');
```

but the result is 404 GET Error. How to deal with it?

**Update**

now the part of code I should use, but don't know how to get cert of existing SSL in the server.

```
var socket = require('socket.io');
var express = require('express');
var https = require('https');
var fs = require('fs');

var options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('path/to/key.pem'), // dont have
    cert: fs.readFileSync('path/to/cert.cert') // dont have
};

var app = express();
var server = https.createServer(options, app);

var io = socket.listen(server);

app.get('/test', function(req, res) {
    res.send('hello world');
    console.log('visited test')
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function (client) {
    console.log("New client !");

    client.on('message', function (data) {
        console.log('Message received ' + data.name + ":" + data.message);

        io.sockets.emit('message', {name: data.name, message: data.message});
    });
});

server.listen(443, function () {
    console.log('listen me on: 443');
});
```

Comment: The .csr is not the certificate.  it's the cert request.  Also, your code doesn't show you creating your `https` server anywhere.

Comment: it is obvious now and that is what I'm asking for community. The reason they not worked is that .pem and .cert files was not generated. And the code was pasted as it is now.

Comment: You need to get a cert first.  The CSR won't help.  Then you need to use the cert + key with the `https` class, not `http`, to set up your listener.

Comment: so how to need a cert over exsisting one? becouse now website is being rechead over https so I don't need to create new one, I need to get existing one somehow - I dont know how.

Comment: Sorry, I don't udnerstand what you're trying to do.  YOu have an existing SSL site --- how does your node site fit into this?

Comment: Im not creating new node site over it. I just need to do real time records machine for exsisting site which runs with SSL. So I became for solution that I need to use nodejs and I can't run it becouse of SSL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to contact your certificate authority (the organization that issued your first ssl certificate) and get a copy of the certificate (the `path/to/key.pem` and `path/to/cert.cert`) or find the existing keys somewhere on your existing server.

If you're running apache, your configuration file will have a section with values for the paths of the .cert and .pem files labeled `SSLCertificateFile` and `SSLCertificateKeyFile`, then just update the paths in your node app to point to them. You also have to make sure that your SSL certificate meets the requirements (for example, needs to be Multi-domain if your node app runs on a different domain, or a Wildcard SSL certificate to run your node app on a subdomain).

The `domain.com.csr` and `domain.com.key` files you found are the private key and certificate request used to generate your initial SSL certificate and aren't going to do anything to enable SSL on your node app.